# How to give option to save a file instead of printing it from internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have written some javascript code to print some information using internet explorer using the below code .

```
                if (isPrint==1)
                {
                  window.print();
                }
```

isPrint is a variable just to mark the document is for printing.
I got the task to save it in a local copy and as it can be saved while printing in .xps format. I want to create a separate function which can directly save it into the format without showing a print menu.
Can it be done

Answer (score 0):

There is a great tutorial on this available at [Save as in JavaScript tutorial](https://dsgdev.wordpress.com/2006/09/27/save-as-real-data-when-the-page-is-generated-with-javascript-documentwrite/), but the gist of it is that you want the function that I've included below which gets the resulting innerHTML rather than just saving off the JavaScript code.

```
<html id=myhtml>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
  function save()
  {
     var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
        var url =document.URL;
        url = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('\\')+1,url.length);
     var s = fso.CreateTextFile(url, true);
        s.WriteLine('<html id=myhtml>');
        s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('myhtml').innerHTML);
        s.WriteLine('</html>');
        s.Close();
        document.location.href = url;
  }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
  <SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
     document.write("This is my first JavaScript!<br>");
  </SCRIPT>
 <INPUT onclick=save(); type=button value=save> </BODY>
</html>
```